# side by side boxes with full width across all devices

Tags: html, css

I need boxes to show side by side for the same full width of 100% for each box inside my container and across all device dimensions. 
Now the following works, it shows what I am after, however this solution does not work on the actual physical devices such as tablets and smartphones, I dont know why, but is it possible to change my code so that the effect actually shows how designed on the physical devices (and not just in my browser and resizing the browser to see the effect)?

```css
.box2 {
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 0;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  background-color: #FFF;
  color: #000;
  border: 2px solid #A10000;
  height: auto;
  width: calc((100% / 2) - 5px);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.row {
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
.container {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .box2 {
    width: calc((100% / 3) - 5px);
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .box2 {
    width: calc((100% / 6) - 5px);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <a href="#" class="box2 dfs-1-sm" title="1"><h1>1</h1></a>
      <a href="#" class="box2 dfs-2-sm" title="2"><h1>2</h1></a>
      <a href="#" class="box2 dfs-3-sm" title="3"><h1>3</h1></a>
      <a href="#" class="box2 dfs-4-sm" title="4"><h1>4</h1></a>
      <a href="#" class="box2 dfs-5-sm" title="5"><h1>5</h1></a>
      <a href="#" class="box2 dfs-6-sm" title="6"><h1>6</h1></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres one way you can do that using flex boxes instead, which will create a platform independent rendering that you can be sure will work everywhere:

CSS Code for FlexBox setup

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <center>
    <div id="flexcanvas">
      <div id="container" class="flexChild rowParent">
        <div class="flexChild" id="box1">
          <h1>Box #1</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="flexChild" id="box2">
          <h1>Box #2</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="flexChild" id="box3">
          <h1>Box #3</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="flexChild" id="box4">
          <h1>Box #4</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="flexChild" id="box5">
          <h1>Box #5</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="flexChild" id="box6">
          <h1>Box #6</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </center>


<style>
#flexcanvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px !important;
}
.rowParent,
.columnParent {
    display: flex;
    /* wrapping flex boxes causes platform independent arrangement*/
    
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-content: stretch;
    align-items: stretch;
    flex-direction: row;
    /* webkit-based browser support */
    
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-box-pack: start;
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
    -webkit-align-content: stretch;
    -webkit-box-align: stretch;
    -webkit-align-items: stretch;
    /* MS-based browser support */
    
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-pack: start;
    -ms-flex-align: stretch;
    -ms-flex-line-pack: stretch;
}
.columnParent {
    flex-direction: column;
    /* webkit-based browser support */
    
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    /* MS-based browser support */
    
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
}
.flexChild {
    flex: 1;
    align-self: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px black solid;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -webkit-align-self: auto;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex-item-align: auto;
}

</style>
    </body>
</html>
```

The above snippet basically creates flexible boxes that can warp and change to accomodate any device no matter how large or small, and is probably the best way to go.

In terms of viewing pages as they would appear on devices, try the "responsive design view" option in the developer tools of most modern browsers.

enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

Set the display of the div child of the `.row`, which is the third div, to `flex`, like this:

```
.container > .row > div {
    display: flex;
}
```

Comment: might not work across all browsers like that if they dont have support for the flex CSS attribute - but will work on most browsers...

Comment: it just needs to add prefixes according to browser they are using such as -webkit (Chrome), -moz (Firefox), -ms (IE), and -o (Opera)